# RadioGroup Check(id) not triggering setOnCheckedChangeListener in android

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

I am having a radiogroup and added radio buttons dynamically to it. I am using radiogroup.check(id) for selecting the radiobutton inside Radiogroup.

```
v = new RadioGroup(ctx);
int count = 0;
for (String Str : valueStr.get(Position)) {
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(ctx);
    rb.setId(count);
    rb.setTag(valueStrID.get(position).get(count));
    rb.setText(Str);
    if (formFieldObject.getFD_ValueField().equals(String.valueOf(Str))) {
        rbposition = count;
   }
   rb.setTextSize(fontSize);
   ((RadioGroup) v).addView(rb);
   count++;
}
```

And calling this method for selection

```
((RadioGroup) v).check(rbposition);
```

But this is not triggering the Checkedchangelistener. What is the problem with the code?

Comment: show us where do you set the listener

Comment: i ve tried the listener before the check method but no luck.

Comment: Did you try to set directly to radiobutton? RadioButton b = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yourradiobutton);
b.setChecked(true);

Comment: if i am using setChecked() it is working. but through check() it is not.

Comment: In Pr38y answer , i used setChecked() before adding it to the radiogroup. so the mutual selection dint work. Now it is working. But still not able to get it to work with the above method.

Comment: @Saret My mistake. I think what you came to say is right. We have to set the listener before check() method. If i am giving it at the last then it is not listening to the checkedchange(). Now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Call `rb.setChecked(true)` to check it.

```
v = new RadioGroup(ctx);
int count = 0;
for (String Str : valueStr.get(Position)) {
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(ctx);
rb.setId(count);
rb.setTag(valueStrID.get(position).get(count));
rb.setText(Str);
rb.setTextSize(fontSize);
((RadioGroup) v).addView(rb);
if (formFieldObject.getFD_ValueField().equals(String.valueOf(Str))) {
    rbposition = count;
    rb.setChecked(true);
}


count++;
}
```

Comment: previously i tried it with setChecked method only. But it gives me problem when i am selecting next radiobutton. It discards the mutual selection property. ie) It shows like both radio buttons are selected.

Answer (score 1):

my code is working just check. I think your calling this method before adding the RadioButton to RadioGroup, then it should not work

```
((RadioGroup) v).check(rbposition);
```

please check the my code its working perfectly.

```
public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        RadioGroup radioGroup;
        ArrayList<String>valueStr=new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayout ll;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.third_activity);
    ll= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

            valueStr.add("ONE");
            valueStr.add("TWO");
            valueStr.add("THREE");



            radioGroup=new RadioGroup(ThirdActivity.this);
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {


                   switch (checkedId){
                       case 0:
                           Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this,"RadioButton ONE Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           break;
                       case 1:
                           Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this,"RadioButton TWO Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           break;
                       case 2:
                           Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this,"RadioButton THREE Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           break;
                   }
                }
            });

            int count = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<valueStr.size();i++) {
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(ThirdActivity.this);
                rb.setId(count);
                rb.setTag(valueStr.get(i));
                rb.setText(valueStr.get(i));

                rb.setTextSize(16);

                ((RadioGroup) radioGroup).addView(rb);
                if(count==1){
                    radioGroup.check(count);
                }

                count++;
            }
            ll.addView(radioGroup);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually at first i had it this way only. but later changed it We have to register the listener before the check() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = new RadioGroup(ctx);
int count = 0;
for (String Str : valueStr.get(Position)) {
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(ctx);
    rb.setId(count);
    rb.setTag(valueStrID.get(position).get(count));
    rb.setText(Str);
    rb.setTextSize(fontSize);
    ((RadioGroup) v).addView(rb);
    if (formFieldObject.getFD_ValueField().equals(String.valueOf(Str))) {
        rbposition = count;
    }
    count++;
}

((RadioGroup) v).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                
    }
});

((RadioGroup) v).check(rbposition);
```

I am giving the listener before the check() method and it is working now.